# JAVA FX : How to set menubar in same scene of fxml view

Tags: java, javafx

I wouldlke to add my menubar from my borderpane but the problem actually is I loaded my view (FXML) on primary stage. I wouldike to add my menubar at top of my view :

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/view/home/home.fxml"));

// Create MenuBar
MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();

// Create menus
Menu fileMenu = new Menu("File");
Menu editMenu = new Menu("Edit");
Menu helpMenu = new Menu("Help");

BorderPane rootTop = new BorderPane();
rootTop.setTop(menuBar);

primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 900, 600));
primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(rootTop, 900, 600));

primaryStage.show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 900, 600));
primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(rootTop, 900, 600));
```

sets the scene two times. The second `Scene` overrides the first one, so you won't be able to see your loaded FXML.

What you can do is **embed** your FXML in your `BorderPane`:

```
BorderPane rootTop = new BorderPane();
rootTop.setTop(menuBar);
rootTop.setCenter(root);

primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(rootTop, 900, 600));

primaryStage.show();
```